# Why does (= (vector nil)  (vec nil)) return false?

Tags: vector, clojure, equality

Is this just a quirk, or is there some fundamental concept that implies this?

Comment: vec makes something a vector while vector makes a vector around something.

Answer (score 21):

vec converts into a vector(nil becomes an empty vector) while vector creates a vector with the given elements.

> (vec nil) => []
>   (vector nil) =>
>   [nil]

you could have entered these expressions into a repl to see their results and why they're not equal.

Answer (score 6):

`user> (vec nil) ; => []`

`user> (vector nil) ; => [nil]`

`user> (= *1 *2) ; => false`

Why should these be equal?

Comment: Your own paste seems to indicate that they're not equal.

Comment: My question was rhetorical.